# Change Bootstrap 4 Navbar expand direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking around for a way to have my navbar, which is mounted at the bottom of my home page, expand upward when the toggle icon is clicked. I used a Bootstrap 4 Navbar template that scales with window size. Do I need to use CSS, JavaScript, or jQuery to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: did you look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/  there is a fixed bottom class